# Does the given function in the functional equation even exist?

Tags: functional-equations

**Given Problem:**

$f$ is a function that satisfies the 3 following properties:

1. $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$
2. $\sqrt{f(x)}\ge\frac{f(x)+f(1)}{2}$     for some x within the given domain
3. $\frac{f(n)}{f(1)} = 2n - (f(1))^2 , n\ge2$

It is required to find all such functions.

*Clarification: Consider that* $0\notin\Bbb{N}$

**Given Solution:**

The first condition states that the domain and codomain of $f$ is $\Bbb{N}$. So, AM-GM inequality can be applied here as all the numbers that we are working with are positive.
Applying the Inequality, we can get:
$$\sqrt{f(x)}\ge\frac{f(1)+f(x)}{2}\ge\sqrt{f(1)f(x)}$$

But since $f(1)\ge1$, we have $$\sqrt{f(x)}\le\sqrt{f(1)f(x)}$$
So, the inequalities given above are actually equalities. 
Hence, for the inequality to hold, we must have $f(1) = 1$

Substituting this in 3rd condition gives:$$f(n) = 2n-1, n\ge2$$

Note that $f(1) = 2\cdot1-1$

So, $$f(n)=2n-1, n\in\Bbb{N}$$

**My Confusion:**

The second property does not hold for $x=2$.

**L.H.S.**
$=\sqrt{f(2)}$
$=\sqrt{2\cdot2-1}$
$=\sqrt{3}$
$=1.7320508...$

**R.H.S.**
$=\frac{f(2)+f(1)}{2}$
$=\frac{3+1}{2}$
$=2$

So, we have **L.H.S.** $\lt$ **R.H.S** Which clearly violates the second property. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please choose your tags with care. Your question is **not** about `functional-analysis`.

Comment: It is said for some $x$ within the given domain, not for all.

Comment: Note that since $ f ( 1 ) = 1 $, the second property holds for $ x = 1 $, and thus $ f ( x ) = 2 x - 1 $ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Is the answer that no such function exists? Because that seems the case here

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the answer is that no such function exists, if you notice your inequality with $f(1) \geq 1$ gives us

$$\sqrt{f(x)}\ge\frac{f(1)+f(x)}{2}\ge\sqrt{f(1)f(x)} \geq \sqrt{f(x)}$$
So, not only do we get $$f(1)f(x) = f(x)\implies f(1) = 1$$
We also get
$$\sqrt{f(x)}=\frac{f(1)+f(x)}{2}=\frac{1+f(x)}{2} \tag{1}$$

Now, we have arrived at $$f(n) = 2n-1$$
Now, substituting that in $(1)$ we see
$$\sqrt{2n-1}=\frac{2n-1 + 1}{2}=n \implies n^2 - 2n +1=0 \implies n=1$$

So, no such function exists